# What is the name of the resetting ratchet component found most often in head rests?

Tags: seat

There is a component which I've seen most often in car seat headrests which acts as a ratchet. You can pull the headrest forward and it will lock at steps until you pull it too far, and it will reset all the way back.

It's sort of a ratchet mechanism which resets after a certain range of motion.

I don't know what it's called. I've tried "resetting ratchet", "resetting step lock", and many other queries.

Do you know the name of this component?

---

I tried asking in DIY and they sent me here (https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214833/what-is-the-name-of-the-resetting-ratchet-component-found-most-often-in-head-res)

Comment: So, what do you need to tepair? Which bit is broken - the name won’t change the repair.

Comment: I'm not repairing, but building something from scratch.  I need this component for what I'm making.

Comment: Well, try 3 or 4 bar chain - mechanical terms...

Comment: Hmmm...  I tried searching both of those and didn't find anything.  Would you mind sharing a link?

Comment: I call it a Pain In The Arse.

Comment: How about a "positioning pawl with end release"

Comment: Thank you!  If you want to add that as an answer and include this link (https://patents.google.com/patent/US3441119A/en), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an Allsop Redmond Notebook Stand that uses a "positioning pawl with end release" at each pivot point. You can raise the tilt angle click-click 6 times. On the seventh click the mechanism releases and the stand lowers back to its bottom position.

A more complex version exists on the tab key mechanism of some typewriters. See patents.google.com/patent/US3441119A/en .

Answer (score 1):

I've found them called "Headrest Hinge" on Amazon and Ebay.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=headrest+hinge